# How to add custom message deserializer for kafka consumer(using sarama lib)

Tags: go, apache-kafka, consumer, sarama

Serialized Message is getting produced by a java microservice, same message i need to consume in another service written in golang
I am using sarama lib for kafka consumer in golang, I am getting message, but its distorted because of serialization by producing service
Need help to add custom deserializer to consumer for incoming message in Go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding the serialization type in message header before publishing the message.

Let say you want publish a buffered from json string, you can add/set header content-type json. So when you consume the message from another service firstly read the header with key content-type, if the value is json then you use json serialization.